# Better using one JLabel or multiple ones?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am creating the instructions for my little game. 
Snippet:

```
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("text1");
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("text2");
JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("text3");
JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel("text4");
```

or it's better using only one with the use of `html`?

Other snippet:

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("<html>text1<br>text2<br>text3<br>text4</html>");
```

Which one consume less resources and it's faster?

Comment: `Which one consume less resources and it's faster?` - that should not be a consideration. You do what is easier to manage and maintain in your code. Another option might be to use a JTextPane or JTextArea. You can make the component non editable. A text pane allows you do use attributes to highlight text.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip. Which one do you suggest? JTextArea or JTextPane?

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to see which components best meets your requirements.